Cupy copy numpy array to existing device array
I would like to copy a numpy array on an existing, pre-allocated, gpu array.
I've seen that cupy offers the functions copy and copyto, however the former does not allow to specify the destination array, while the latter works only between device arrays.
Is there any way to achieve copying a numpy array to the device making usage of pre-allocated memory?

Not sure if there is any way of doing this in the high-level API, but it is certainly possible using the low-level API. See e.g. cupy.cuda.runtime.memcpy()

What paleonix commented indeed works fine, i.e. something like this:
cupy.cuda.runtime.memcpy(cupy_array.data.ptr, numpy_array.ctypes.data, numpy_array.nbytes, cupy.cuda.runtime.memcpyHostToDevice)

